# AngularJs: Copy the data using ng-value but model does not update

Tags: angularjs

I'm having an issue on updating or assigning the value or data into the model using ng-value.

I would like to copy any values in the DisplayName model to CopyDisplayName and using below directives i was able to do that, But the problem is the model CopyDisplayName doesn't have any value when I submit my changes. It can only have if I inputted it manually.

```
<input type="Text" ng-model="DisplayName" ng-disabled="true" />
<input type="Text" ng-model="CopyDisplayName" ng-value="DisplayName" />
```

Forgot to include that the `DisplayName` is disabled.. the data will came from service call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **ngValue**
>
> Binds the given expression to the value of  or input[radio], so that when the element is selected, the ngModel of that element is set to the bound value.

You can take a look in this [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngValue).

So basically, the one you're doing right now will not work.

You can do this in your angular controller:

```
$scope.copyValue = function () {
    $scope.copyDisplayName = $scope.displayName; 
}
```

In html:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="displayName" ng-change="copyValue()" />
```

Comment: Thanks for your input.. I also forgot the detail that the displayName is disabled and ng-change will not trigger :(... the value on that will came from ajax call...

Comment: So after your ajax response, in success function, just set the value of your displayName. Then set the value for copyDisplayName by assigning or by doing angular.copy. Just do a little experiment. :)

Comment: @whoknows If you want to copy from `displayName` to `copyDisplayName`, shoudn't the `copyValue` function say `angular.copy($scope.displayName, $scope.copyDisplayName)`? Or even `$scope.copyDisplayName = $scope.displayName`, since they're strings?

Comment: @DzinX Sorry, my bad. I will update my answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Just assign one variable to another:

```
// in the controller
$scope.CopyDisplayName = $scope.DisplayName;
```

If you need to keep them in sync (and for some reason, you don't want to just use the same variable), then you can keep them updated via `ng-change`:

```
<input type="Text" ng-model="DisplayName" ng-change="CopyDisplayName = DisplayName" />
```

Directives like `ng-value` (or `ng-checked`) only toggle the attributes in the DOM - they do not alter the View Model.

Comment: Thanks for your input.. I also forgot the detail that the displayName is disabled and ng-change will not trigger :(... the value on that will came from ajax call...

Comment: @Chris, ok... so, then just copy one to the other in the `.then` of the ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `$watch` on `DisplayName` as:

```
$scope.$watch('DisplayName',function(newValue, oldValue){
   console.log(newValue +":"+oldValue)
   $scope.CopyDisplayName = newValue;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To have copy updated you need copy value by reference. For that you need to wrap `displayName` to object: 
`$scope.model = {DisplayName: 'val'};` and make a copy of it: `$scope.modelCopy = $scope.model;`

```
 <input type="Text" ng-model="model.DisplayName" ng-disabled="true" />
 <input type="Text" ng-model="modelCopy.DisplayName" ng-value="DisplayName" />
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4qupwf9g/6/)

Answer (score 0):

what you can do in controller is watch the model and copy that value whenever it is changed($watch will do that for you) you dont need ngChange on the HTML.

```
$scope.$watch('displayName', function() {
      $scope.copyDisplayName = $scope.displayName; 
});
```